# can cron schedule a variable change in one of your scripts (node.js)

Tags: node.js, cron

is it possible to get cron to go into one of your scripts on the server and change a variable at a certain time?

Comment: Can you explain your question better?

Answer (score 0):

cron simply fires a program/script at a given time. You would need an intermediate script/program to change the variable.   But you could schedule a script to run that changes your variable.

Comment: I have the following code:

var category = 'sport';
var sub_category = 'golf';

 request.post(
'...',
{ json: {"category":category,"sub_category":sub_category,"contest_status":1} 
},

how would another script look to change the above variables?

Comment: Just a thought.  why not let cron call node for you? Implement whatever change logic within the node script?

cron is kinda one-shot deal. You use it to call more sophisticated things (programs/scripts).

Answer (score 0):

You can install `cron` npm module to do it:

```
$ yarn add cron
```

And then in your code:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

let i = 0;

new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('You will see this message every second');
    i++;
    console.log(`Value of i = ${i}`);
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```